# Existence of vector norm such that the induced operator of Jordan block smaller than eigenvalue

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, normed-spaces

Suppose we have a Jordan block with dimension greater than $2$. For example, let us denote
\begin{align*}
J = \begin{pmatrix}
\lambda & 1\\
0 & \lambda
\end{pmatrix}.
\end{align*}
I am wondering whether there exists some vector norm $\| \cdot \|_v$ (the subscript denotes some vector norm) such that the induced operator norm of $J$ has the property $\|J\| = \sup_{\|x\|_v} \|Tx\|_v = |\lambda|$.

I think the answer is no. We know any vector induced norm has the property $\lambda \le \|J\| \le \lambda + \varepsilon$ for every $\epsilon > 0$. But in the classical construction for this proof, it seems like we cannot reduce $\epsilon$. But how to prove this rigorously? Suppose we have some vector norm on $\mathbb C^2$. Let $x \in \mathbb C^2$ with $\|x\|_v = 1$. How do we claim following strict inequality
\begin{align*}
\|J\| = \sup_{\|x\|_v=1} \| Jx \|_v > |\lambda|.
\end{align*}

Comment: If $\|\cdot\|_v$ is given by $\|x\|_v = \|Sx\|_p$ (where $S$ is an invertible matrix and $\|\cdot\|_p$ denotes the $p$-norm for some $1 \leq 1 \leq \infty$), then the induced norm will satisfy $\|J\| > \lambda$.  I'm not sure if there are any norms besides these.

Comment: $\sup_{\|x\|_v}$?

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo: Is my notation confusing? I edited the question. The subscript denotes ''some'' vector norm.

Comment: Shouldn't it be $\sup_{\|x\|_v = 1}$?

Comment: Yes, you are right. Thanks. Somehow I was thinking $p$-norm.